# Combining the data of randomly selected participants with dplyr

Tags: r, performance, random, dplyr, combinations

I have the following data frame 'df'.
Each participant (here 10 participants) saw several stimuli (here 100), and made
a judgment about it (here a random number). For each stimuli, I know the true
answer (here a random number; a different number for each stimuli but always 
the same answer for all participanst)

```
participant <- rep(1:10, each=100)
stimuli <- rep(1:100, 10)
judgment <- rnorm(1000)
df1 <- data.frame(participant, stimuli, judgment)
df2 <- data.frame(stimuli=1:100, criterion=rnorm(100))
df <- merge(df1, df2, by='stimuli') %>% arrange(participant, stimuli)
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

1) Taking n randomly selected participants (here n is between 1 and 10).

2) Computing the mean of their judgments per stimuli

3) Computing the correlation between this mean and the true answer

I want to perform step 1-3 for all n (that is, I want to take 1 randomly selected participants and perform steps 1-3, then I want to take 2 randomly selected participants and perform steps 1-3 ... 10 randomly selected participants and perform steps 1-3. 
The results should be a data frame with 10 rows and 2 variables: N and the correlation. I want to work only with dplyr.

My solution is based on lapply. Here it is:

```
participants_id = unique (df$participant)      

MyFun = function(Data) {

HelpFun = function(x, Data) { 
# x is the index for the number of participants.
# It Will be used in the lapply call bellow
participants_x = sample(participants_id, x)
filter(Data, participant %in% participants_x) %>% 
  group_by(stimuli) %>% 
  summarise( mean_x = mean(judgment),
             criterion = unique(criterion) ) %>%
  summarise(cor = cor(.$mean_x, .$criterion))
  }
 N <- length(unique(Data$participant))

lapply(1:N, HelpFun, Data) %>% bind_rows()
}  

MyFun(df)
```

The problem is that this code is slow. Since every selection is random, I 
perform all this 10,000 times. And this slow. On my machine (Windows 10, 16 GB) 1000 simulations take 2 minutes. 10,000 simulations takes 20 minutes. (I also tried with loops but it did not help, although for some reasons it was a little bit faster). It has to be a solution faster. After all, a computations are not so complicated.
Below I wrote 100 simulations only in order to not interfere with your computer.
    system.time(replicate(100, MyFun(df), simplify = FALSE ) %>% bind_rows())

Any idea about making all of this faster?

Comment: to start with, how about moving ``participants_id = unique (Data$participant) ``in the outer loop

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggestion. Yet, it is still very slow...

Comment: @Meir How slow? On my machine 100 replications takes 11.5 seconds. I ask because I'm curious why you need it to be faster; will you eventually be scaling this up to more replications or higher N? Is it something you hope others will be running on their own computers at some point, or are you just worried about your own computing time?

Comment: I add some precisions. Ideally I would like 10,000 simulations. 1000 simulations take me 2 minutes and 10,000 about 20 minutes. I think something has to be wrong with my code for being so slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` and for loops we can get 10 times faster solution.
My function:

```
minem <- function(n) { # n - simulation count
  require(data.table)
  participants_id <- unique(df$participant)    
  N <- length(unique(df$participant))
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  setkey(dt, stimuli)
  L <- list()
  for (j in 1:n) {
    corss <- rep(0, N)
    for (i in 1:N) {
      participants_x <- sample(participants_id, i)
      xx <- dt[participant %in% participants_x,
               .(mean_x = mean(judgment),
                 criterion = first(criterion)),
               by = stimuli]
      corss[i] <- cor(xx$mean_x, xx$criterion)
    }
    L[[j]] <- corss
  }
  unlist(L)
}

head(minem(10))
# [1]  0.13642499 -0.02078109 -0.14418400  0.04966805 -0.09108837 -0.15403185
```

Your function:

```
Meir <- function(n) {
  replicate(n, MyFun(df), simplify = FALSE) %>% bind_rows()
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Meir(10),
  minem(10),
  times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#  Meir(10) 1897.6909 1956.3427 1986.5768 1973.5594 2043.4337 2048.5809    10   b
# minem(10)  193.5403  196.0426  201.4132  202.1085  204.9108  215.9961    10  a
```

around 10 times faster

```
system.time(minem(1000)) # ~19 sek
```

### Update

If your data size and memory limit allows then you can do it much faster with this approach:

```
minem2 <- function(n) {
  require(data.table)
  participants_id <- unique(df$participant)    
  N <- length(unique(df$participant))
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  setkey(dt, participant)
  L <- lapply(1:n, function(x) 
    sapply(1:N, function(i)
      sample(participants_id, i)))
  L <- unlist(L, recursive = F)
  names(L)  <- 1:length(L)
  g <- sapply(seq_along(L), function(x) rep(names(L[x]), length(L[[x]])))
  L <- data.table(participant = unlist(L), .id = as.integer(unlist(g)),
                  key = "participant")
  L <- dt[L, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
  xx <- L[, .(mean_x = mean(judgment), criterion = first(criterion)),
          keyby = .(.id, stimuli)]
  xx <- xx[, cor(mean_x, criterion), keyby = .id][[2]]
  xx
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Meir(100),
  minem(100),
  minem2(100),
  times = 2, unit = "relative")
# Unit: relative
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   Meir(100) 316.34965 316.34965 257.30832 257.30832 216.85190 216.85190     2   c
#  minem(100)  31.49818  31.49818  26.48945  26.48945  23.05735  23.05735     2  b 
# minem2(100)   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000     2 a
```

But you will need to test yourself.

Comment: Thanks. is it faster because the use of data.table instead dplyr? Or because your use of for loop instead of apply?

Comment: @Meir because of `data.table`. Using `lapply` more or less is the same as `for` loop, so that usually does not impact performance.

Comment: Unbelievable. I was hoping to find a solution with dplyr. It is so surprising that data.table is so faster than dplyr.

Comment: @Rtist the last approach is not so fast because of `data.table`, but because we do not do any calculation in lapply, only the sample index selection. So this answered your question? if so, then you probably should accept this answer...